# Is there a general closed solution to $\int \frac{x}{\dot{x}} dt$?

Tags: integration

let $x = x(t)$ be a function. Is there any closed-form solution to the following integral?

$$\int \frac{x}{\dot{x}} dt$$

I couldn't imagine any relation (if there is any!) between it and the following integral $$\int \frac{\dot{x}}{x} dt = \ln x + C$$

Comment: Depends on $x(t)$. It may or may not. Definitely no general solution.

Comment: For instance, if $x$ is a constant function, then the integrand isn't even defined.

Comment: Some examples $x=e^t$, then the integral is $t+C$.  If $x=t^n$, then the integral is $\frac{t^2}{2n}+C$. I don't see any pattern.